# Is $Y -X \sim { \chi }^{ 2 }$ if $n>m$?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, chi-squared

Suppose that $X\sim { \chi  }^{ 2 }(m)$ and $Y\sim { \chi  }^{ 2 }(n)$, and X and Y are independent. Is $Y - X \sim { \chi  }^{ 2 }$ if $n>m$?

No, $X-Y$ can take on negative values and a random variable with a $\chi^2$ distribution cannot. I dont understand this last line can you give me a example of this situation

Comment: For $X-Y\sim \chi^2$, we require that $\mathbb{P}(X-Y<0)=0$ (since the pdf of a $\chi^2$ distribution has support within $[0,\infty)$). But this is clearly not the case, hence $X-Y\not\sim \chi^2$.

Comment: @projectilemotion why is clearly that $\mathbb{P}(X-Y<0) \not = 0$

Comment: @projectilemotion   Can you give me an example of a case when $Y-X$ is negative? In other words, when is $Y-X$ negative? Or, rather, why $\mathbb {P} (Y-X <0)> 0$?

Comment: @projectilemotion On the other hand, what happens with $Y-X$ also happens with $X-Y$? Is it the same case for both ?, that is, does neither tristribute chi-squared for the same reason mentioned above?

Comment: Same question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3860147/321264.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The difference between chi-square variables is not a chi-square variable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3860147/the-difference-between-chi-square-variables-is-not-a-chi-square-variable)