# The difference between chi-square variables is not a chi-square variable.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose that $X\sim \chi^2(m)$, $Y\sim \chi^2(n)$, and $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Is $Y-X\sim \chi^2$, if $m<n$? 
I think that this is false, but I don't find any counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The support of $X-Y$ is $\mathbb{R}$ thus it cannot be  chi squared distributed

Edit: as an example you can take

$X\sim \chi_{(2)}^2$ and $Y\sim \chi_{(4)}^2$ and calculate the distribution of $Z=Y-X$ analythically. It is not difficult.

You have

$$F_Z(z)=\int_{-z}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2}e^{-\frac{x}{2}} dx\int_{0}^{x+z}\frac{y}{4}e ^{-\frac{y}{2}}dy$$

for $z<0$

And

$$F_Z(z)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2}e^{-\frac{x}{2}} dx\int_{0}^{x+z}\frac{y}{4}e ^{-\frac{y}{2}}dy$$

For $z \geq 0$

Comment: Can you be more specific, please? Some example?

Comment: @SAS : added an example